# preg_replace: how do I strip off all white space and &nbsp;?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

how do I strip off all white space and `&nbsp;`?

I have this as a input in a wrapper I create,

`[b] &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; bold &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [/b]`

so before turning the text to bold, i want to strip off all white spaces and &nbsp, and turn it into `[b]bold[/b]`,

```
$this->content = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]\s\s+(.*?)\s\s+\[\/(.*?)\]/", 
                "[$1]$2[/$3]", 
                $this->content);
```

but it does not work! can you help please?

Comment: The problem is simply that php doesn't recognize `&nbsp;` as a whitespace character, simply because it is infact just a string of 6 characters. If you want to use regexps for that, you'll need to tell php to explicitely match `&nbsp;` as well.

Comment: where do you get these `&nbsp;`? may be not to add it at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another solution

```
$this->content = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/(.*?)\]/", "[$1]$2[/$3]", html_entity_decode($this->content));
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need for a regex based solution. You can simply use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as:

```
$input = "[b] &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; bold &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [/b]";
$input = str_replace(array(' ','&nbsp;'),'',$input);
echo trim($input); // prints [b]bold[/b]
```

Comment: This will remove the whitespace outside the `[b]`, too. But I don't know whether that's expected behavior or not.

Comment: Looking at his sample input/output looks like thats what he wants.

Comment: Except that the sample doesn't show text outside of the tags.

Comment: And what if get one more &nbsp; in next string he is parsing? This is very bad answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->content = preg_replace(
    '~\[(.*?)](?:\s|&nbsp;)*(.*?)(?:\s|&nbsp;)*\[/\\1]/', 
    '[$1]$2[/$1]', 
    $this->content
);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work either. The original question didn't show the `&nbsp;` characters that OP wants to be removed. Also your solution will not work at all, since the square brackets are not escaped, and all your grouping doesn't help either.

Comment: @poke: I don't get what you want to say. The closing square bracket `]` doesn't need to be escaped. All I did was take the OPs regex, remove unnecessary parts and add recognition of `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @nikic: Huh? Did you change your answer in between?

Comment: @poke: I think you are referring to another answer. I didn't change this one.

Comment: @nikic: o.O Yeah I think so, my bad then.. *confused* - Could you slightly change your answer (add a space or something) so I can remove the -1 again?

Answer (score 2):

A little late to answer but hopefully might help someone else.  The most important thing while extracting content from html is to use [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in php. Then all other string operations become a breeze.  Even foreign characters can be replaced by directly copy pasting characters from browser into the php code.

The following function replaces `&nbsp;` with empty character.  Then all white spaces are replaced with empty character using `preg_replace()`.

```
function clean($str)
{       
    $str = utf8_decode($str);
    $str = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $str);
    return $str;
}

$html = "[b] &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; bold &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [/b]";
$output = clean($html);
echo $output;
```

> [b]bold[/b]

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the spaces with empty strings, e.g.

```
preg_replace("/(?:\s|&nbsp;)+/", "", $this->content, -1)
```

The -1 causes the replace to hit every instance of the match.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that would work is:

```
$this->content = trim(str_replace('&nbsp;','',$this->content));
```

PHP Manual links:

trim() http://us.php.net/trim

*note: This is assuming $this->content contains only the string posted by OP

Answer (score 0):

To give you a complete solution with regular expressions as well:

```
$this->content = preg_replace( '/\[([a-z]+)\](?:&nbsp;|\s)*(.*?)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\[\/([a-z]+)\]/', '[$1]$2[/$3]', $this->content );
```

But in this case you should rather combine the whitespace removal and bbcode transformation to make sure that the tags are correctly:

```
$this->content = preg_replace( '/\[b\](?:&nbsp;|\s)*(.*?)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\[\/b]/', '<b>$2</b>', $this->content );
```